# How to download files to Wordpress?

Tags: uploads, links

How can I download file to wordpress? I mean, we have a link of a file for example

> http://example.com/myVideo.mp4

which is a large file. So I'm not able to download it to my computer, then upload it to wordpress.

Is there anyway or plug-in to download it directly to wordpress website? So wordpress server will download the file.

**Note:** *I know it's possible to download it to website's FTP server from SSH and using Wget utility. But I want to know is it possible from wordpress directly?*

Answer (score 1):

@Amirreza Nasiri - Yes that is possible. I have used following plugin to import large size files into WordPress Media library. Please take a look at this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

I have no affiliation with plugin. I had used it for one of my client project and just found it as suitable suggestion for this question :)

Comment: I think this is what I wanted. I'll test it as soon as I get home.

Comment: Would be nice if you can highlight the major functionalities of the plugin. Also, you **must** declare your affiliation to the plugin. Please file an [edit] to your answer and state your affiliation. Thanks

Comment: @PieterGoosen , I think we should be able to assume that wordpress.org plugins are legit otherwise it is just madness. (in this case I checked ;) doesn't really answer the question but nothing wrong with pointing to it.)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I have no affiliation with plugin. I had used it for one of my client project and just found it as suitable suggestion for original question. Still, please let me know if any edits are required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether its possible to download an external file directly to WordPress. But you can simply embed the video in your WordPress page without downloading it from the source. For that just click on 'Add media' button, then choose 'Insert from URL' and paste your video URL in the text box and finally click 'Insert into post'. This will embed the video inside your post or page.

Comment: I didn't talk about "Embedding". that URL is only an example one and I don't want to embed it.